# Mysql time diff between the dates in same column

Tags: mysql, time, diff

I want to take the "Created" time difference between stalled(NewValue) and stalled(OldValue) for the particular ticket_id

Note : This is my first post.I can't attach the pic due to some restriction.

```
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Ticket_id | OldValue | NewValue | Created             |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 20100     | new      | wip      | 2012-10-01 07:38:18 |
| 20100     | wip      | stalled  | 2012-10-01 10:12:14 |
| 20100     | stalled  | wip      | 2012-10-01 22:09:39 |
| 20100     | wip      | open     | 2012-10-02 01:03:26 |
| 20100     | open     | stalled  | 2012-10-02 01:03:26 |
| 20100     | stalled  | wip      | 2012-10-03 06:55:42 |
| 20100     | wip      | open     | 2012-10-03 19:24:53 |
| 20100     | open     | stalled  | 2012-10-03 19:24:53 |
| 20100     | stalled  | open     | 2012-10-04 19:28:48 |
| 20100     | open     | resolved | 2012-10-04 21:01:17 |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: CAn you be more specific on your expected output result?

Comment: We do not ask you to attach the pic. Just explain what you want. In your example there are more then one `wip` in the `OldValue` / `NewValue` fields for the same `ticket_id`. Between which values you want to take the difference? Show desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

```
SET @dte:=CURRENT_DATE();
SELECT DATEDIFF(Created, @dte),@dte:=Created FROM table ORDER BY Created
```

This will show you the difference between the two values (except for the first record). You could add an extra IF or just don't show the first date.

Comment: Actually I don't need the current date&time. I just want the timediff between the stalled(NewValue) and stalled(OldValue).

Comment: Did you test it? This will show the diff between the old and new value. Except for the first row (since there is no difference to calculate). So for the first row it will calculate the difference with today. You can also set it to null or what ever value. The value in that first row will always be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came to.  I'm not sure if you're working with JIRA, but I was (looks like you may be).  I needed to find the time a particular JIRA ticket remained in a certain status (despite the number of times it has changed).

```
SELECT
  ThisLog.issueid,
  b.NEWSTRING,
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,ThisLog.created,PrevLog.created)*-1) AS "Status Time"
FROM
  changegroup    AS ThisLog
LEFT JOIN
  changegroup    AS PrevLog
    ON  PrevLog.issueid = ThisLog.issueid
    AND PrevLog.created = (SELECT MAX(created)
                          FROM changegroup
                          LEFT JOIN changeitem AS b1
                          ON changegroup.ID = b1.groupid
                          WHERE issueid = ThisLog.issueid
                          AND created < ThisLog.created
                          AND b1.field = "status"
                          AND b1.NEWSTRING = "Pending Customer")
LEFT JOIN changeitem AS b
ON ThisLog.ID = b.groupid
WHERE ThisLog.issueid = 82720 AND b.field = "status" AND b.NEWSTRING = "Pending Customer";
```